# How can I put a vertical scrollbar in a Rich Text field in xPages?

Tags: xpages

I input the text in a help database in native Notes and display it to a user on the web.  The content goes beyond the page size on the web.  How can I use a scrollbar in that Rich Text field?

```
            <xp:td align="center">
              <xp:inputRichText
                    id="inputRichText1"
                    value="#{document1.Body}"
                    readonly="true">
              <xp:this.style><![CDATA[color:darkblue;text-align:left;border:solid;border-width:thin;padding-top:15.0px;
                        padding-bottom:15.0px;padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;width:800px]]></xp:this.style></xp:inputRichText>
            </xp:td>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the content goes beyound the page size"? The rich text field itself expands its content. Have you added the the rich text field inside a surrounding div? Please show us your code for your XPage.

Comment: https://www.mymlmtracking.com/A5590B/MyMLMHelp.nsf?OpenDatabase

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.lotusMain {
    height: auto;
}
```

Currently `height` is set to `200%`. This is not enough for some of your rich text fields. With `auto` it takes the height needed.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Take a look at this link: https://mymlmtracking.com/A5590B/MyMLMWeb.nsf/xpPageWhatYouGet.xsp.  I have to have the left column set at 400% because I want the background to go all the way to the length of the main window.  I tried auto and it goes about a centimeter.  Any suggestions on how to make that automatic?  The background on the left column scrolls along with the main window.....

Comment: Set `.lotusForm .lotusContent, .lotusMain {height:auto;}` and `.lotusColLeft{height:100%}`